# Обезопасить отправку формы и обработка ее запросом.

Tags: алгоритм, php, безопасность

Запрос может подать только тот, кто заплатил. Злоумышленник же может  просто вбить параметры в браузере (н-р в адресной строке) и запрос обработается. 
В голову приходит только одна идея. ПОсле оплаты на телефон (или email)посылать ключ подтверждения, который будет ждать обработчик. И то, где эти ключи хранить? в БД? а не получит ли вор и туда доступ?

Посоветуйте, может есть какие-то готовые решения?
Спасибо.

Comment: что у вас за злоумышленники такие ? используйте ssl да ? и это... паранойя хороша, только когда она шизоидная, просто паранойя ведёт к гибели индивидуума.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял, пользователь платит асинхронно (подтверждение платежа может прийти и сразу и через день-два), и получает доступ к сервису - может выполнять запросы много раз.

В таком случае нужна авторизация пользователя: логин/пароль, и опционально куки, чтобы не каждый раз логиниться. В БД хранить таблицу аккаунтов: статус (оплатил?), срок действия подписки (не навсегда же они купили себе доступ), ip с которых заходил. При смене адреса можно просить перелогиниться, если приложение не для мобильников. И только через https работать, разумеется.

Без регистрации тоже можно, если привязываться к кукам и ip. Ссылка в письме "спасибо за оплату, вот ваша ссылка" ведёт на скрипт, который

1. запоминает этот визит: дату, ip, user-agent;
2. ставит куки, по которой потом можно пользоваться правами этого юзера.

Ещё раз, всё только по https.

В другие разы юзер заходит сразу на сайт, который проверяет эту куки, сравнивает с user-agent'ом и, может, ещё и IP, и если всё ок - обслуживает.

Если не ок - надо снова пройти по ссылке в том письме, и проставить себе куку.

И ещё раз: **всё только по https**!

Comment: У меня будет наверное даже проще. 
Пользователю не нужно логиниться и мне не обязательно (я думаю) запоминать куки.
2 функции: 
1. Подать объявление
2. Продлить объявление (мне не важно кто продлит его, если это будет оплачено)
Все равно использовать вашу схему?

Answer (score 0):

1) в форму добавить дополнительное, скрытое поле, например хэш от передаваемых данных, с id в базе, и обрабатывать только те данные, у которых этот хэш верный.

2) если посылать ключ, то опять же, лучше в бд хранить, или его формировать в зависимости от известных параметров, которые уже лежат в базе, например время оплаты, id, и т.д.

а вообще, можешь поискать на счет CSRF (Cross-site request forgery)

Comment: по первому. А разве злоумышленник не сможет посмотреть этот хэщ  и тоже его послать?

Comment: Радик hash - в php например номер сессии в куке лежит, данные сессии на сервере - умышленник их не видит, а токен у клиента, даже если клиент умыслил зло то ничего кроме того, что "я это я" он сделать не сможет, а то-что он заплатил определяется авторизацией в той или иной форме. А от прослушки траффика спасает ssl, а от чувака-по-середине спасает ssl подписанный одной из доверенных контор ($30 кажется это стоит если не 10)

Comment: т.е. первый способ подразумевает регистрацию-авторизацию?
"а то-что он заплатил определяется авторизацией в той или иной форме." создавать личный кабинет?